# YUI Panel Resize issues

Tags: dialog, resize, yui, panel, overlay

I am having trouble while using the YUI panel as a dialog.

I have a dialog object created with javascript on page load:

```
$J = jQuery;
dialog = new YAHOO.widget.Panel("dialog", { width: "300px", fixedcenter: true, close: true, draggable: true, zindex: 4, modal: true, visible: false });
```

Then when I call my loadDialog() function from event on the page:

```
dialog.setBody("<iframe id=\"ifrDialog\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\"></iframe>");
dialog.hideEvent.subscribe($$F.endDialog);
dialog.render(document.body);
// Set iframe
$J("#ifrDialog").get(0).contentWindow.location.replace(url);
```

Then the tricky part was that I needed to resize the Panel and the IFRAME object *AFTER* the IFRAME finished loading its document. I got the width and height of the IFRAMES document and then resized the IFRAME to fit the document without scroll bars, then I resized the YUI Panel to contain the IFRAME correctly.

After this was done I make a call to:

```
dialog.center();
```

and this positions the YUI Modal Panel correctly in the center of the screen. Everything is great the first time. Originally when I wanted to close the dialog I tried to remove it from the document altogether by using the destroy() method but I kept getting a config null reference error so I simply hide the dialog now. The real problem arises when I try to show the dialog again for the same page. The Panel appears correctly as it should except now the browser window has vertical scrollbars when it shouldn't.

Is the Modal overlay growing for some reason? Is there some way to * reset * the Panel or remove it from the document so that it can be added dynamically when needed?

Also, same widget but different issue. I ran into another interesting situation after I had resized and repositioned the YUI Panel. The underlay did not grow to match the Panel's new size. I had to manually go and resize the underlay. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Daniel

Comment: Hey @Daniel P, how did you resize panel and iframe object after iframe finished loading? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you thought about using:

```
$("yourpanel_ID").remove();
```

To remove the panel from the DOM,
 this way, you will start with a fresh one anytimes.